# PostgreSQL indexed table performance suddenly drops

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, indexing, bigdata

I have a project that uses a big and growing table in PostgreSQL database. I use PostgreSQL 11.
I have an index (btree index) on a column which is a hash signature, which must be unique.
This DB is growing and I need to make it work for a huge amount of data as I have millions (and sometimes tens/hundreds of millions) of new records every day and I currently don't want to delete them.
The main use case is only inserting: I just need to insert records and make sure they don't collide with another record's hash signature.

I am doing it using COPY command - I write my data in batches (currently 10,000 records per batch but that's dynamic) and then insert them to the DB using the next command:

```
COPY tableName FROM STDIN (FORMAT csv)
```

I made many performance tests on the DB and it was pretty satisfying, I first filled it with a few hundreds of millions of records, and then made batch insertions, one threaded and multi threaded. The performance flowed around an average of 0.3-0.5 ms per record in batch when I had about 500 millions records.
Obviously when a table is pretty empty I am getting way better results, starting from 0.01-0.02 ms per record, and getting pretty stable at 0.2 ms per record when I already have 150-200 millions records.

Kept going on with my tests and tried to integrate this into my bigger program that needs to include this db and insertions. Suddenly the big table performance dropped, I started seeing very lousy performance, around 4 ms per record in batch. I thought that might be me using the project wrong in my program, but I then went back to only inserting, and the performance sucks. It is very weird because it sometimes gets up to 20ms per record in batch, and sometimes goes back to 1-2 ms per record in batch.
I then created a new empty table with the same index, filling it just with simple COPY command as I showed above. The performance was great, but after about 180 millions records this table also "dropped" performance very sudden. It's not an ongoing process where you see performance getting worst for time.. It just suddenly gets to a very bad performance.

I currently have another table which I managed to fill up to almost 200 millions records and the performance is still great (around 0.1-0.2 ms per record in batch). So this seems very weird - It is not the DB itself as I have two tables with very similar sizes, same index, same data-templates inside them, and one of them gets about 10 times worse performance.

I am using a pretty solid server for my DB - 32 GB RAM, high CPU, SSD storage, I don't see my insertions even using all of the CPU/RAM.

I have no idea where to check for a solution, if the whole DB was giving a bad performance I would say it makes sense, or if I was reaching a certain amount of records in a table that from there the performance sucks.

I would love to hear any advice on how to approach this. If any more relevant information is needed please tell me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unrelated: have you tried partitioning this table? 200m records isn't that much, but if you keep growing like this you will soon reach a few billion records - and the fun will start for real ;) good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To check the uniqueness and to insert the value into the index, it has to fetch the index leaf page that would/will contain the value.  Once all your index leaf pages don't fit in RAM, this will become limited by the random seek time on your drive.  Then it will dirty that page, and it will have to be written (eventually), which can also be a bottleneck.  You say you have SSD, but not all SSD and their drivers are created equal.  Have you benchmarked it to see what the random read/write performance is?

You can mitigate this by having your batches sorted by the unique key.  That way records which have keys in the same leaf page are likely to find the page already in cache, and already dirty.  This saves on both the read and the write.  But for this to work, the batches must be large.  If the batch has fewer records than the index has leaf pages, then "adjacent" records are not likely to be sharing leaf pages.